# Removing one-to-many entry

Tags: symfony-2.8

i have problem with my entity , i remove entry in my arraycollection, i see result, but it did'nt take effect in my bdd.

on Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BaseEleveBundle\Entity\Dossier", mappedBy="eleve", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $dossiers;

foreach ($listfinancement as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['check'] == 1) {
            echo " remove dossier done";
            $this->removeDossier($this->dossiers[$value['clef']]); //<-- remove 

        }
    }

public function removeDossier(Dossier $dossier){
    $this->dossiers->removeElement($dossier);
}
```

on controller

```
if($form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($eleve);

            $em->flush();

        }
```

I see the result if i use $eleve, but on reload page, my remove desapear, remove don't take effect in BDD

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution after 1 hour of search, just after posting just and orphanRemoval=true on config anotation

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BaseEleveBundle\Entity\Dossier", mappedBy="eleve", cascade={"all"},orphanRemoval=true)
*/
private $dossiers;
```